# build dynamic filters in sqlalchemy python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to generate/build sqlalchemy query dynamically using dynamic columns and their values.

Example - 
I have a table in SQL called "Convo" and it has columns like - UserID, ConvoID, ContactID.

I need to get rows based on the below criteria.

```
criteria = (('UserID', 2), ('ConvoID', 1) ,('ContactID', 353))
```

I have used "Baked query" logic for this. But Some how I am not able to run this query successfully.

Below is the my code.

```
criteria = (('UserID', 2), ('ConvoID', 1) ,('ContactID', 353))
baked_query = bakery(lambda session: session.query(tablename))
for key1 in condition:
    baked_query += lambda q: q.filter(tablename.key1 == condition[key1])
    result = baked_query(self.session).all()
```

I am getting error as -

```
AttributeError: type object 'Convo' has no attribute 'key1'
```

Please help me out with this

Comment: You probably want `getattr(tablename, key1)` instead of `tablename.key1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
criteria = (('UserID', 2), ('ConvoID', 1) ,('ContactID', 353))

query = session.query(tablename)
for _filter, value in criteria:
    query = query.filter(getattr(tablename, _filter) == value)
result = query.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using dynamic keys and "simple" equality checks, the [filter_by](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html?highlight=filter_by#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) method might be more convenient, as it takes keyword arguments that match you property names and assembles that into where clause.

So your iterative query construction could look like that:

```
baked_query = bakery(lambda session: session.query(tablename))
for key, value in condition.items():
    baked_query += lambda q: q.filter_by(key=value)
```

Plus, since `filter_by` takes mulitple keyword arguments, you can probably simplify your query construction to a single `filter_by` invocation:

```
baked_query = bakery(lambda session: session.query(tablename))
baked_query += lambda q: q.filter_by(**condition)
```

All of the above obviously assuming that your `condition` variable refers to a dictionary.