# How to make SQL Alchemy and_ dynamic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am taking user input as a comma-separated value.

```
name, grade, admission_number
```

The user will provide at least one of them. I need to build the `and_()` such that it filters accordingly.

`session.query(Student).filter(and_( Student.name == name, Student.grade == grade ))`

If the user provides only the name of the student then the above statement will look for a student where the grade is an empty string.

I need to be able to build that `and_` based on whatever values the user provides.

Comment: You could also instead just apply multiple `filter()` calls to the query based on the input.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39138179/5320906

Comment: @IljaEverilä so you're saying the only way to do that would be to add multiple `filter()` calls in subsequent `if` blocks

Comment: No, it's *one* way to do it. You can of course for example form a list of criteria and unpack the list as arguments to `and_()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Ohk.. that is a better construct. I'm sorry but can you just put up that unpacking example? It'll be very helpful. New to Python environment.